# Coloring treemap by parent node in highcharts styled mode

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts, treemap

I'm trying to create a treemap in highcharts styled mode and color the nodes by their parent nodes like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/treemap-with-levels/).

In styled mode, the only way i was able to achieve this is to assign a (css) className individually to each child node:

```
{
  name: 'Anne',
  parent: 'A',
  value: 5,
  className: 'highcharts-color-1'
}
```

See my example: https://jsfiddle.net/kimpalita/1tLue9s0/

I was wondering if anyone is able to suggest a more elegant/simplified way of doing this without having to repeat the className property in every single data point.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that a parent node and its children has a css class to differ them from the other nodes. But you can still add code to add a parent class name to its children which allows you to omit specifying class name for each point.

```
 chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        this.series[0].data.forEach(p => {
          var parent = p.parent;
          var className = parent && this.get(parent).className;
          if (className !== undefined) {
            p.graphic.addClass(className)
          }
        })
      }
    }
  },
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/k0gw0dop/